# How do I make mailto: form work in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

http://www.web-via.com/NinaRose/club/

The form works fine on a plain html page, but within wordpress it is giving me a "Please enter valid email address" error.

```
<form action="mailto:maxp@businessrocket.net" enctype="text/plain" style="background-image:url('http://www.web-via.com/NinaRose/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/NinaBRozeClub.jpg') height:464px;" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" style="background-color: white; height: 18px; left: 210px;     position: relative; top: 318px; width: 187px;"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height: 25px; left: 78px; opacity: 0; position: relative; top: 350px;"/>
</form>
```

I'm not sure what is causing the conflict here, either Wordpress or the Popup Ninja plugin that the code is sitting in, nor do I have a clue how to resolve the issue.

Many Thanks in Advance,
Ken

Comment: Search "Please enter valid email address" in your source code. There must be some js validation there.

Comment: Than it is really hard for us to debug from here. You have to help yourself & debug it. Also try to change the name of the email element & check if validation stills come up.

Comment: How do I go about debugging? And what do you mean by changing the name of the email element? Thanks Rikesh

Comment: I mean by change `name="email"` to something `name="emailAddress"`. May be validation is putted on its name. So you can get rid of it by doing this.

Comment: Same issue when changing name :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is coming from line 82 of front.js.  It's trying to validate an address found with this code:

```
var email = pn("#popup_form #email").val();
```

It's expecting your email field to have an id of `email` somewhere within another element with an id of `popup_form`.  Try adding `id="popup_form"` to your `form` element and `id="email"` to the email field.

Or better, check where those `id`s are in your working HTML page, and put them on the same elements in your WordPress page.